# mutate the post body before it reaches the server according to the data in the server(Fetch API)

Tags: reactjs, rest, react-redux, fetch-api

I have a react-redux-form that Post its input data to a JSON in the server called **feedback**, but before the POST I want to add a new property image:**`feedback_images/(${feedback.length + 1}).jpg`** in order to show randomly the images with messages and names... in carousel.

I successfully mutate the body before it reaches the server:

```
export const postFeedback = (formData) => (dispatch) =>{
      
    var mutatedFeedback = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(formData)); //This line for changing the object 
                                                               //from not extensible to extensible
    mutatedFeedback.image = `feedback_images/(${feedback.length + 1}).jpg`;

    fetch(url + 'feedback', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(mutatedFeedback),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        credentials: 'same-origin'
    })
```

}

**This is the Feedback array of objects in server:**

```
 "feedback": [
//Before mutating the body
    {
      "firstname": "Anis",
      "lastname": "Sina",
      "phone": "00000000",
      "email": "anis@gmail.com",
      "message": "First Feedback",
      "id": 1
    },

//After mutating the body
    {
      "firstname": "Daniel",
      "lastname": "Scout",
      "phone": "00000000",
      "email": "daniel@gmail.com",
      "message": "Second Feedback",
      "image": "feedback_images/(undefined).jpg",
      "id": 2
    },
  ]
```

BUT as you can see there **"image": "feedback_images/(undefined).jpg",** it's **undefined** which as you all aware it should be undefined, because I need to get the JSON array from the server before I call it there.

This is my question how I can get the 'feedback' JSON array in order to use it there?

[Images folder:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpCf4.jpg)

[My purpose from doing this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9hXS.jpg)

Comment: i think feedback is an object and there is no length thats why it gives undefined

Comment: it's an array of objects, once you fetch it from the server you can get its length,

Comment: mutatedFeedback.image = `feedback_images/(${feedback.length + 1}).jpg`;

Comment: than how you had prop in to array?

Comment: This is where my problem bro I need to get this array of objects **feedback** before I try to get its length

Comment: Isn't it just `feedback_images/${formData.get('id')}.jpg`?

Comment: The coming object from the redux form has no id property, however I tried your suggestion and it throw me an error **TypeError: formData.get** is not a function